# How to keep data after closing the program.(without using textfile,data outside)

Tags: wpf, database

Example :

1.When i using program start int x = 5;

2.Do something until x = 10

3.Closing program

4.When a relaunch program x will be equal to 10 (not 5)

Comment: I would use registry, see [Read, write and delete from registry with C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3389/Read-write-and-delete-from-registry-with-C)

Comment: Do not use the Registry without good reason. See [When - and why - should you store data in the Windows Registry?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/268424/1136211)

Comment: I stand corrected :)

Answer (score 2):

Here the **Application Setting** will come into play.

```
Proiperties -> Settings
```

[image]

This will strore our data as XMl formatted.

Action can be applied through both programmatically and manually.

**Programmatically:**

**Create:**

```
SettingsProperty property = new SettingsProperty(nameofthesetting);
property.DefaultValue = "Default";
property.IsReadOnly = false;
property.PropertyType = typeof(bool);
property.Provider = Properties.Settings.Default.Providers["LocalFileSettingsProvider"];
property.Attributes.Add(typeof(UserScopedSettingAttribute), new UserScopedSettingAttribute());
Properties.Settings.Default.Properties.Add(property);
Properties.Settings.Default.Reload();
property.DefaultValue = HereYourValue;
```

**Update :**

```
Settings.Default.YourSettingsName=NewValue
Settings.Default.Save();
Settings.Default.Reload();
```

reference,

[How do I get around application scope settings being read-only?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1687321/how-do-i-get-around-application-scope-settings-being-read-only)

[How to update appSettings in a WPF app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/305529/how-to-update-appsettings-in-a-wpf-app)